# How do I get a numbers-only keyboard on a TVML textField?

Tags: tvos, tvml

I'm building a TVML/TVML-based tvOS app and want to use a numbers-only keyboard on my `textField` element but the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/tvos/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/ATV_Template_Guide/SimpleMultimediaElements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015064-CH20-SW6) currently doesn't say how to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the `textField` TVML element, you can specify a `keyboardType` attribute with a value of `numberPad` to get a number pad keyboard.

```
<textField keyboardType="numberPad">Placeholder</textField>
```